# How to find text file in android emulator?

Tags: android

Hi I am new to Android. I push files to Android device emulator. Image files are in Gallery and audio files are in Music. How can I view the text file in the android device emulator.( I heard  android doesn’t come with Text Editor form stack overflow). I don’t want to open Text file I need to find if the text file is in the device or not. My file explore application list the available file in the sdcard. It lists the text file name also but in the device emulator how can I find the text file?????

Comment: I don't really understand the question...you want to get the file name by java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the following commands from your command line and see if that helps:

```
1. adb shell (a # prompt opens)
2. ls
3. cd /data/data
```

now you can see the list of folders that belong each to its own package/application.
cd into the folder that interests you most and see what's inside. Many applications store some additional files here. The text file you're looking for could be there.

You can still view the contents of a text file in Android by writing 'cat [filename]' in the console.

Answer (score 4):

It can also be viewed through Eclipse using the File Explorer view when the emulator is running.

```
Window->Show View->Other..->Android->File Explorer
```

When the emulator is not running, File Explorer shows nothing.