# creating log file while launching the android application

Tags: android

I want to create a log file in the sd card while launching my android application and want write  logs into that file.How it can be done? If anybody knows please help me..

Answer (score 1):

I have created class for that:

```
public class Logger {

public void appendLog(String text,String filename)
    {       
       File dir = new File("sdcard/YourFolderName");
       if(!dir.exists())
       {
           dir.mkdirs();
       }

       File logFile = new File("sdcard/YourFolderName/"+filename+".txt");

       if (!logFile.exists())
       {
          try
          {
             logFile.createNewFile();

          } 
          catch (IOException e)
          {
             // TODO Auto-generated catch block

             e.printStackTrace();

          }
       }
       try
       {
          //BufferedWriter for performance, true to set append to file flag

          BufferedWriter buf = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(logFile, true)); 

          buf.append(text);

          buf.newLine();

          buf.close();

       }
       catch (IOException e)
       {
          // TODO Auto-generated catch block

           e.printStackTrace();

       }
    }
```

}

in method you can pass log details and txt file name :)

Comment: I want to create the log file for every day.say for instance if iam ruuning the application today means i want to create the log file with todays's date and so on.shall we do like that?

Comment: I created the file  but file name is not displaying while i verified it in the DDMS perspective.

Comment: are you checking in emulator? it won't create it in emulator.you need to check in real device

Comment: i created the log file in the sd card.But it creating as read only file.How can we make it as read write?

Comment: I have not tried it yet..as i dont wont log file writable..but you can do that by setting flag logFile.setWritable(true). it works for api level 9 or more..

Comment: how can we check in emulator whether the data was written in the logfile or not?

Comment: check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2910829/how-to-find-text-file-in-android-emulator

Answer (score 0):

```
private File cacheDir;

      if(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(
           android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))

        cacheDir=new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"MyLog");
     if(!cacheDir.exists())
        cacheDir.mkdirs();
```

It will create a Directory for you in the SDcard and You can create a file and write your Logs in there.

```
 File f = new File(cacheDir, filename);   //(File dirPath,String filename)
```

Using this line you can create a file in your directory and write the logs in that file...

If this helps mark it as correct :)

Comment: I want to create the log file for every day.say for instance if iam ruuning the application today means i want to create the log file with todays's date and so on.shall we do like that?

Comment: Of-course you can; just name the file as current Date and check for the date and create new file everyday you write a Log

Comment: if you want to create file everyday, you create a service. Register it in broadcast reciever. on some fixed time in a day (say 12:00 pm everyday) create file.

Comment: I dont have an idea to create log file with today's date on application launch.please help me if anybody knows...

Comment: I created the file but file name is not displaying when i verified it in the DDMS perspective.

Comment: i created the log file in the sd card.But it creating as read only file.How can we make it as read write?

Comment: how can we check in emulator whether the data was written in the logfile or not?

Answer (score 0):

**Create Log file in SD Card**

Use This method. Just pass the message to this method as a argument.

```
   public static void addRecordToLog(String message){
    //Not in release: Log.d("SmartCalendar", message);
    LogRecord logRecord = new LogRecord(Level.INFO, message);
    FileHandler logger = null;
    if (logger == null) {
        try {
            logger = new FileHandler(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Android" + Environment.getDataDirectory() + "/dwivedi/files/log_"  + new Date().getTime() + ".xml");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("SmartCalendar", e.toString());
            // it seems that no dirs on sd card
            File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Android" + Environment.getDataDirectory() + "/dwivedi/files/");
            dir.mkdirs();
            try {
                logger = new FileHandler(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Android" + Environment.getDataDirectory() + "/dwivedi/files/log_"  + new Date().getTime() + ".xml");
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                Log.e("SmartCalendar", e1.toString());
                return;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("SmartCalendar", e.toString());
            return;
        }
    }
    logger.publish(logRecord);      
}
```

**Note:** *Don't forgot the provide the permission for the READ and WRITE External Storage:*

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```